# How do we express this position: to lie across the rail bars?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Look at the picture

[image]

Do we say "**they are lying across the rail bars**"?

Also, see this picture

[image]

Do we say "**the cat is lying across the bar**"?

Or what are the idiomatic way of saying that?

Comment: Those are rail tracks, not 'bars'.

Comment: Or, in British English, just 'rails'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people are lying (down) across the (railway) tracks.

The cat is sprawled (rather than **lying**) across the **spindle** securing the legs of the stool.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spindle_(furniture)

Comment: "Spindle" is a very specific term in furniture design and feels quite out of place here. I can't imagine a casual speaker using it in this context. I would probably describe it as the chair's **leg brace**.

Comment: True, it's a technical rather than a typical description, but accurate nonetheless: https://www.homestratosphere.com/chair-parts/

Comment: In British English it's a **stretcher**.